# Move some already existing and pushed commits to a new branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a feature branch about topic X, but in this branch I did commits that would be better in feature branch Y, but I forgot to create it before beginning.

Is there a way to move this commits to a new branch? It does not matter if the branch is branched from X or master or anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are the latest commits, see the instructions [here](http://effectif.com/git/move-commit-from-one-branch-to-another). Otherwise, you can cherry pick the commits into the other branch, then delete them from the old. But remember: [if you have already pushed the changes, rewriting history is generally a bad idea](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/2010/5/5/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html).